# script sharePoint online libraries files via PS (site admin permissions only)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I need to script all documents in a site library. I am site admin on each of the sites in the site collection but I am not site collection admin/SharePoint tenant admin.

I tried with the Sharepoint online module for PS first, but it looks like I would have needed tenant admin. Then I tried with CSOM and PnP, but none of them worked.

Can you provide a PS script or link in order to connect to my site (while being just site admin not site collection admin), in order to pick up libraries/lists etc from there?

The last script that I used :

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" <br/>
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$SiteUrl="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MyRootSiteName" 

#credential 
$UserName="emailAddress@Contoso.com" 
$Password ="Passwrd"
 
#Create Credential object from given user name and password 
$Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
 
#Set up the context 
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Cred 
#Get the Web Object 
$Web = $Ctx.web 
$Ctx.Load($Web) 
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

The error that I got at the last line is:

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system."

Please let me know if I can connect to SP online via PS as only site admin and be able to script libary files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to connect to a SharePoint Online site as site admin only. As to the error "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.", this may be caused by that your account is MFA (Multi-factor authentication) enabled. If yes, either MFA must be turned OFF or you have to follow the methods described in How to Connect to SharePoint Online with MFA-enabled accounts from PowerShell. To connect to SharePoint Online through CSOM PowerShell script with a Multi-factor authentication enabled account, use this PowerShell:

```
 $SiteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MyRootSiteName/MySubSiteName"
 
 #Setup Authentication Manager
 $AuthenticationManager = new-object OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager
 $Ctx = $AuthenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext($SiteUrl)
 $Ctx.Load($Ctx.Web)
 $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

I want to confirm with you what do you mean by "script libary files" exactly? Do you want to list all files names in a Document Library using PowerShell? If yes, take a reference to this article: [SharePoint Online: PowerShell to List All Files Inventory in a Document Library](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-all-files-in-document-library.html). Replace the code which connects you to SharePoint Online with the code above.

Comment: the code worked. thank you Allen_MSFT !

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. Please don't forget to accept answer if my answer is helpful to you.